# Как сравнить текущее время с заданным php?

Tags: php, дата

Написал следующий код, но - пустота

```
        if(date('H:i') >= strtotime('19:00') && date('H:i') < strtotime('10:00')){
            print '<div class="schedule closed">Сейчас закрыты</div>';
        }
```

Comment: Приведи дату в timestamp: `strtotime(date("H:i"))`

Comment: Вместо date('H:i') используйте time()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сравнивать строки:

```
if (date('H:i') >= '19:00' || date('H:i') < '10:00') {
    print '<div class="schedule closed">Сейчас закрыты</div>';
}
```

Comment: `if (date('H:i') >= '19:00' || date('H:i') < '10:00')` - кто-то заработался?)